# Position from velocity time graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, velocity

[image: Click here for the image]

I have taken Calculus before but unfortunately no equation is given so I have to do it the old way.

An object is at x = 0 at t = 0 and moves along the x axis according to the velocity-time graph shown below

I am asked to find the final position x of the object at t = 18s.

Here is my logic, but apparently the answer is wrong.

I find the area of each of the sections of the graph. If the graph is below the x axis it's area will be negative. I found the answer to be 97m. I got this from -44+-11+28.5+76+47.5. But this is wrong.

Comment: since you have no intial condition in this question, you can't solve the problem. Please specify the initial condition.

Comment: @BruceLee Sorry, An object is at x = 0 at t = 0 and moves along the x axis according to the velocity-time graph shown below

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: PS the initial velocity is -12 not -11

Comment: Use $d = d_0 + v_0t + 1/2 a t^2$ where $d_0$ is the initial displacement, $v_0$ is the initial velocity, $a$ is the slope of the curve (acceleration) and  $t$ is the time interval. Do the same over all four different parts of the diagram and add them up. Be careful with the signs.

Comment: Using the above equation seems a bit overkill. I would go with the negative and positive area. Basically the displacement is calculated by taking integral of velocity graph, so an area explanation is enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct; your ability to read data from a graph is suspect (the divisions are 2 m/s each).

The initial velocity is -12 m/s, and at time t=9 s it is up to 18 m/s

That should change your answer...